# ElasticSearch 7.7 how can I increase the count of results of whole index

Tags: elasticsearch

I understand that its theres hardcoded limit in Elasticsearch of 10k results per query. What I wanna know if theres any way to search results within this 10k limit but at the same time at least show count of all results for this particular query.

So let's suppose if there are 1M results matching for certain query, the count should show 1M instead of max limit of 10k.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can.

You need to add the below attribute to your `search` query

```
{
    "track_total_hits": true
}
```

It will show you the total count along with default result.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch supports a `/_count` API to result the count of all hits in query

```
GET /index/_count
{

    // your search query here
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     }

}
```

You can add "from" and "size" to visit **specific hits** of response 
Example

```
GET index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

In the returned query response from Elasticsearch, there is a field `response['hits']['total']['value']` which has the count of hits too, but it also has its limitations.

NOTE: `/_count` API doesn't support "from" and "size", it gives you the total count.
for more details visit
[Elasticsearch Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).